# Twilio SMS Repsonse

Tags: python, sms, twilio, messaging, http-status-code-400

I'm playing around with Python and Twilio, attempting to setup an automated response to an SMS. The response comes through when I send a text but none of the other details. My test server also gives a 400 bad request, so it's not understanding what's being requested. I may just be using incorrect syntax since I compiled this code from different examples and text. If anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly or knows the correct syntax I would appreciate the help.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import *

#initialize Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

#route for handling request on endpoint
@app.route("/sms", methods=['POST', 'GET'])

def inbound_sms():
    #gets number that text is sent from
    inbound_num = request.form['From']
    #gets message that was sent
    message_body = request.form['Body']

    reply = MessagingResponse()
    #Sends reply with attached details
    reply.message("Thank you!".format(inbound_num, message_body))
    return str(reply)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are not receiving the number and body in the message because you are missing something in your string formatting. You need to add placeholders for where the number and body will slot into the string using `{}`. Like this:

```
reply.message("Thank you! Number: {}. Body: {}".format(inbound_num, message_body))
```

I don't know why your application would be responding with a 400 response though. It looks correct to me and if Twilio is sending the response then it should be working.

Comment: I'm not sure either, I'll have to look into it further. 

One other question, how do you specify what info you want to be returned to the phone that sends the sms and to the test site? It seems useless to echo back the message and number of the user who sent the text back to them. I'd rather send a response to the user who sent the sms and then print the info of the user (number, message body) to my test site separately.

Comment: Well, for that I would probably save the message that you receive in the webhook into a database for your site, which you can later read the messages from if you want to show them on a site. Then you can send whatever response back to the sender that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the http 400 error by using:

```
request.form.get('')
```

Instead of:

```
request.form['']
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with Flask, but I'm really not sure. I don't know enough about Flask to really say.

Everything showed up correctly on the phones of the senders, but I noticed that my test page would not displace the senders' numbers or text body they sent; only the reply message. So it looked like this:

> Thank you! User: None Message: None

I'm not certain what the issue is there either. I'll probably end up doing something like you suggested using a database.